# How to generate unique sequence id in SQL Server with multiple transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with SQL Server ..

What I want is to generate unique id for every transaction which is pre transaction prior to use commit transactions

Scenario :

There are 10 computers when they will open their web browser then each each browser will display series of unique id's on them like comp 1 will display 101 comp 2 will display 102 and comp 3 will generate 103 ....and so on !

I want to handle this on database end can you guys help me with this

Thanks in advance, guys ....

Comment: So is it MySQL, Oracle or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with single autoincrement column.

When you need another unique id - just insert `null` into that column and retrieve last insert id.

For oracle - create a sequence and use `SELECT sequence_name.nextval` FROM DUAL`

For sql server - create a sequence and fetch it with `NEXT VALUE FOR`

Comment: autoincrement is a wrong technique, because after an aborted transaction the sequence will be broken.

Comment: @armen: there is no such a thing as "broken sequence". Sequence must be monotonously growing and unique. That's it. If you want something else - you simply don't understand what it is for. Thank you.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 is a sequence, 1, 2, 4, 5 is a broken sequence !

Comment: @armen: 1. it's not broken. Where did you find such a term? It's a valid sequence - it's monotonously growing and contains only unique members. 2. It skips the number - so what? Any problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server to generate truly unique ID I suggest using GUID, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @UniqueID uniqueidentifier
SET @UniqueID = NEWID()
```

Comment: the question is how to generate unique `sequence` id !